# Cyclic and abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

A group $G$ has order $25\cdot 47\cdot 17$. Is it cyclic and/or abelian?
I know that a group of order $47$ or $17$ is cyclic, should I somehow use it?

Comment: A group of order $25 = 5^2$ is abelian as well.  All groups of order $p$ or $p^2$ are abelian.

Comment: Is here power = order or power = exponent?

Comment: yeah, of course an order

Comment: So, to be clear, you are asking specifically about a group of order 25*47*17?

Comment: Yes, if this group is cyclic and/or abelian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely abelian.  Hint: Use the Sylow theorems to show that there is only one Sylow $p$-subgroup for $p = 5$, $17$, $47$.

Since there is only one Sylow $p$-subgroup for each $p$, we can deduce that each $p$-subgroup is normal$^{**}$.  From here, we can apply the Theorem 3.3 from the link below to conclude that $G$ is isomorphic to a direct product of it's Sylow p-subgroups, all of whom are abelian.  Of course, the direct product of abelian groups is always abelian.

http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/sylowapp.pdf

Whether the group is cyclic depends on whether the Sylow $5$-subgroup is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{25}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_5$.

---

** This is because, for a specific $p$, all Sylow $p$-subgroups are conjugate to each other.  Therefore, if there is only a single Sylow $p$-subgroup, it is necessarily normal in $G$.